# Searching the iTunes AppStore by application GUID?

Tags: api, search, app-store, guid, itunes

Is it possible to look up an app on the iTUnes AppStore API using the application GUID? (The long hash found in the /User/Applications folder on the device)

The AppStore does have an API for affiliates here : http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

There are some PHP scripts to help query this data too (eg : AppsGeni ) , but I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to look up by GUID.

TIA.